# zeros and poles of $\operatorname{Im} f(z) / \operatorname{ Im z }>0$ using argument's principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Hi everyone I find the following exercise and honestly I'm stuck and I can't see how to use the argument's principle in any way. I'd appreciate any help with the exercise. Thank you.

> Let $f$ a mermorphic function defined on $\mathbb C$ and suppose that $\operatorname{Im} f(z) / \operatorname{ Im z }>0$ for all $z$ outside of the real axis.
>
> Show that the poles and zeros of $f$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ and the zeros and poles are interlaced, that is, between two adjacent poles there is exactly a zero and between two adjacent zeros there is a pole (use the argument's principle).

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution that doesn't use the argument principle.

Let $H^+,H_-$ be the open upper and lower half planes.The condition on $f$ implies $f(H^+)\subset H^+,$ $f(H^-)\subset H^-.$ Letting $Z$ be the set of zeros of $f,$ we see $Z\subset \mathbb R.$

Let $P$ be the set of poles of $f.$ Suppose $a\in H^+\cap P.$ Choose $r>0$ such that $D(a,r)\subset H^+.$ Because $a$ is a pole of $f,$ $f(D'(a,r))\supset \{|z|>R\}$ for some $R>0.$ (Here $D'$ means punctured disc.) That's a contradiction, since $f(D'(a,r))\subset H^+.$ Thus $f$ has no poles in $H^+.$ Similarly $f$ has no poles in $H^-.$ Thus $P\subset\mathbb R.$

Note that if $a\in \mathbb R\setminus P,$ then $f(a) =\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(a+ih).$ This implies $\text{ Im }f(a)\ge 0.$ Similarly, $\text{ Im }f(a)\le 0.$ It follows that $f(a)\in \mathbb R.$ So we have $f$ real on the real axis, except for poles.

Claim: $f'(a)\ne 0$ for all $a\in \mathbb R\setminus P.$

Proof: If not, then let $a\in \mathbb R\setminus P$ be such that  $f'(a)\ne 0.$ Then for $z$ near $a,$ $f(z)= f(a) + c(z-a)^m + O((z-a)^{m+1})$ for some real constant $c\ne 0$ and some $m\in \{2,3,\dots\}.$ WLOG $c>0.$ Then

$$\tag 1 f(a+re^{i\pi 5/(4m)}) = f(a) + cr^me^{i\pi 5/4} +O(r^{m+1}).$$

Because $c>0,$ the right side of $(1)$ is in $H^-$ for small $r>0.$ But $a+re^{i\pi 5/(4m)} \in H_+$ for all $r>0,$ hence so is $f(a+re^{i\pi 5/(4m)}).$ This contradiction proves the claim.

Now to the final destination. Suppose $a,b$ are adjacent zeros of $f.$ If there is no pole of $f$ in $(a,b)$ then for some $\delta>0,$ $f(x)$ is a real differentiable function on $(a-\delta,b+\delta)$ with $f'\ne 0$ in this interval (by the claim). But $f(a)=f(b)=0.$ This contradicts Rolle's theorem. It follows that $f$ has a pole between adjacent zeros of $f.$

Now suppose $f$ has adjacent poles $a,b.$ Then $f$ is a real differentiable function on $(a,b)$ with singularities at both $a,b.$ Furthermore, we know $f'\ne 0$ on this interval by the claim. It follows that $f$ resticted to $(a,b)$ is a bijection onto $\mathbb  R.$ Thus $f(c)=0$ for one and only one $c\in (a,b).$

So between adjacent poles we have a unique zero of $f,$ and between adjacent zeros we have a pole. Could we have more than one pole between adjacent zeros? No, because if  we did, there would be a zero between these poles, showing the adjacent zeros were not adjacent after all, contradiction.

Comment: Does the second paragraph follow from $\lim_{z \to a} |f(z)|=\infty$? Wouldn't we have that for every $R>0$ there is some $0<\epsilon<r$ such that $f(D'(a,\epsilon))\subset \{|z|>R\}$?

Comment: Is it difficult to prove from here that the zeros and poles are simple? Or does the fact that they're interlaced imply it?

Comment: @Twink On your first comment, yes your first line is the reason. The second line is also true, but very easy. If would be true if $f$ were merely continuous. But we need the result I stated. You can prove it as follows: Suppose $f$ has a pole at $a.$ Then $1/f$ extends to a holomorphic function $g$ in some $D(a,r),$ with $g(a)=0.$ By the open mapping theorem, $g(D(a,r))$ contains some $D(0,s).$ Thus $g(D'(a,r))$ contains $D'(0,s).$ Let $h=1/g$ on $D'(a,r).$ Then $h(D'(a,r))$ contains $\{|z|>1/s\}.$ Note that $h=f$ on $D'(a,r).$

Comment: I see. Do we have to assume that $g$ has no zeros on $D'(a,r)$ to define $h$? (I think that can be done using the identity theorem, since $g$ is not identically $0$ in that neighborhood. If it was, the singularity $a$ of $f$ wouldn't be isolated.) If I'd want to prove that the zeros and poles are simple, would I need to use the argument principle as in the other answers or does it follow from your argument?

Comment: @Twink  $f\to \infty$ at $a$ so certainly $f$ is nonzero in some $D'(a,r).$ Therefore $g=1/f$ is nonzero in $D'(a,r).$ To see every zero of $f$ is simple, recall $f'$ is nonzero in $\mathbb R\setminus P.$ Let $a$ be a pole of $f$ of order $m.$ If $m\ge 2,$ then some ray in $H_+$ would get mapped into $H_-,$ contradiction, much like the proof I gave for the claim.

Answer (score 2):

(1) So $w= f(z)$ maps the upper half of the $z$ plane into the upper half of the $w$ plane, and maps the lower half of the $z$ plane into the lower half of the $w$ plane.

As $z(t) $ executes a small simple oriented loop $z=\gamma(t)$ in the $z$ plane the image curve $\Gamma (t) = w(t)= f(z(t))$ traces a closed curve in the $w$ plane . The Argument Principle tells us that this winding number of $\Gamma$ about $w=0$ equals $Z-P$, the difference between the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside $\gamma$.

The winding number  of $\Gamma$ is evidently zero if $\Gamma$ lies strictly on one side of the real $w$ axis. Thus by (1) there are no zeros or poles of $f(z)$  inside  $\gamma$ unless the small loop $\gamma$ straddles the real $z$ axis.

The remainder of the problem can be solved by (2) modeling the meromorphic function locally near a real zero or pole as $f(z)= c z^k$ and  thinking about what restrictions that places on $c$ and $k$.  Next (3) consider the image of a narrow rectangular curve $\gamma$ that encloses adjacent zeros of $f$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the last paragraph could you elaborate on the last paragraph, please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to observe is that $Im(f(z))/Im(z)>0$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ implies that $Im(f)\neq 0$ outside $\mathbb{R}.$ In particular, $f$ does not have a zero outside $\mathbb{R}.$

Next, observe that if $\gamma$ is a curve that lies entirely in upper half-plane or the lower half plane, then $f\circ\gamma$ also lies entirely in the upper half plane or lower half-plane. In particular, the winding number of $f\circ\gamma$ about $0$ is $0.$ It follows from the argument principle that $f$ has no pole in the $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}.$

The last bit is to see that (**)“if $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$ (possible intersecting $\mathbb{R}$), then the winding number of $f\circ\gamma$ about $0$ is either $0$ or $\pm 1.$” (I will leave the justification to you, but if you see it geometrically why this happens, you should be able to write it rigorously.)

Note that (**) Implies your claim. For if there are two consecutive zeroes or poles on $\mathbb{R},$ you can make a circle $\gamma$ such that the two consecutive zeros (or poles) are inside the circle (and no other zero or pole). Argument principle tells you that winding number of $f\circ\gamma$ about $0$ is $2$ Or $-2.$
(In fact, it also follows that every zero and pole is simple.)

Comment: In the  third paragraph you say that the winding number about $0$ is $\pm 1$ for any closed simple curve $\gamma$, but in the last paragraph you're saying that there is a $\gamma$ such that the mentioned winding number is $\pm 2$ or $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's a contradiction. That's why there can not be two consecutive zeros or poles.

Comment: Wow I see. And the winding number of $f \circ \gamma$ would be $2$ or $-2$ in case that the zeros or poles have multiplicity $1$, if they have greater multiplicity, the winding number would be $>2$ or $<-2$, is that right?

Comment: You are right. I shoulf have mentioned that.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why the winding number of $f \circ \gamma$ about $0$ is either $0$ or $\pm 1$. I tried to write the following explanation: if $\gamma$ intersects $\Bbb R$, there are two points of intersection, and those points are sent to real numbers by $f$, so $f \circ \gamma$ intersects $\Bbb R$ at two points, the part of $\gamma$ in the upper half plane stays there, and the same for the lower half plane, so $f \circ \gamma$ can wind only once. If it cointains $0$ in the interior, it's $\pm 1$, depending on the orientation, and $0$ otherwise. Is that the correct argument?